# Mysql2 gem problem after upgrading to Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, 64-bit, osx-snow-leopard

I upgraded to Snow Leopard recently and after having troubles with MySQL I upgraded it as well. I followed [these instructions](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard) and built MySQL by myself using [these sources](http://mysql.borsen.dk/Downloads/MySQL-5.1/mysql-5.1.53.tar.gz).

Now MySQL server works fine, but I can't get Mysql2 gem working.

I keep getting this error when starting any Rails3 app:

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2009.10/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2009.10/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)
 /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2009.10/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2009.10/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

I tried everything, but I'm still getting the same error. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: How did you fix this in the end?

Comment: Unfortunately I had no success (my system was really messed up after the upgrade) so I decided to go with clean install which was needed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing MySQL 64 bit from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)
I had the same problem and it worked for me , 
also try using [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/)
some version of ruby might not work properly so it's pretty easy to change between them with rvm .